# Describe all groups which contain no proper subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Describe all groups $G$ which contain no proper subgroup.
I did not understand the meaning of the question actually. Any help would be appreciable, thank.

Comment: Have a look at (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1036019)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group with no proper subgroup.
This means that for any subgroup $H$ of $G$, either $H=1$ or $H=G$.

Let $x$ be a nontrivial element of $G$.
Then $\langle x\rangle$ forms a subgroup of $G$.
By hypothesis, $G=\langle x\rangle$. Hence $G$ is cyclic.

Suppose $G$ is infinite, then $G\cong \Bbb{Z}$.
But $2\Bbb{Z}$ is a nontrivial proper subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$, a contradiction.
Hence $G$ is finite.

Suppose $|G|=ab$ where $a,b>1$
Then $\langle x^a\rangle$ forms a nontrivial proper subgroup of $G$; a contradiction.
Hence $G$ is of prime order.

So we have a conclusion that is

> A group with no proper subgroup must be cyclic of prime order.

Comment: But it asks for *all* groups with no subgroup, this is insufficient, we must also prove that all cyclic groups of prime order have no subgroup.

Comment: @Karthik for cyclic groups with prime order, subgroups can only be of order 1 or prime (Lagrange theorem), thus they have no proper subgroups

Answer (score 0):

What do we know about a group $G$ if the only subgroups that it has are $G$ itself and the trivial subgroup? *Hint*: This has something to do with cyclic groups.